# Does vector.swap() and vector.erase() free all the allocated memory if the vector is a vector of vectors?

Tags: c++, vector

```
vector<vector<double>> a;
for (int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    vector<double> v(i+1);
    iota(v.begin(),v.end(),1);
    a.push_back(v);
}
a.erase(a.begin()+10);    
vector<vector<double>>(a).swap(a);
```

Question 1: is the memory associated to a[10] freed after a.erase()?

Question 2: is the memory associated to all other vectors freed after swap?

Comment: Unclear question. `swap()` takes a parameter.

Comment: BTW: `iota(v.begin(),v.end(),1);` does nothing here.

Comment: `swap()` does not free any memory, it simply swaps around the internal memory pointers of the two `vector` objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) yes, the object (`vector<double>` here) is destroyed. But it is worth noting that the outer `vector` (the one you called `erase()` on) will not change its capacity.

2) yes, it would be emptied. You can also call `a.clear()` but it won't change your outer vector's capacity.

You can *request* removal of the unnecessary capacity by calling [`shrink_to_fit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit) (C++11 and later only), but it's not binding.

Comment: For 1), `erase()` destroys the object(s) that are being erased from the vector, but it is not guaranteed to free the underlying memory that is allocated for those slots in the vector if `erase()` only decrements the vector's `size` but not its `capacity`.  Especially when erasing objects in the middle of the vector and not at the end.

Comment: For question 1, even if a[10] itself is a vector, the memory would still be freed?

Comment: The question explicitly asks about *memory associated with `a[10]`*

Comment: @Resorter yes. The destructor will be correctly run.

Comment: @krzaqL your edit is wrong, since `erase()` *does* change the `size`, and it *may* change the `capacity`, depending on the implementation and index(es) being erased.

Comment: Regarding to @RemyLebeau 's comment, which part of the memory is not freed?

Comment: @Resorter: The outer vector contains an array of inner `vector<double>` objects.  When erasing objects from the outer vector, the objects themselves are destroyed, but their slots in the outer vector's array are not deallocated, they are re-used for other objects, either existing objects that get moved down the array when erasing from the middle of the vector, or new objects that get pushed back later after erasing from the end of the vector.

Comment: @RemyLebeau In my example, a[10] is a vector of double precision numbers of size 11. After a.erase(), how large is the memory associated to the slot in the outer vector's array?

Comment: Your `double`s have been deallocated. What is left is `sizeof(vector<double>)` - likely size of 3 pointers.

Comment: @krzaq I saw that a.clear() does not free the memory associated to the slots of the outer vector too.

Comment: @Resorter: do you understand what an array is and how it works? You have an outer vector containing an array of 100 inner objects. You are erasing the 11th object (which itself contains 11 `double`s) from that array. The object itself gets destroyed (and its array of 11 doubles is freed accordingly), but the outer array itself is still allocated to hold 100 objects, though only 99 of them are now valid (`capacity` remains 100 though `size` is decremented to 99). The 12th and subsequent objects get moved down the array, and the last array slot is now open for later reuse.

Comment: @Resorter: and yes, `clear()` does not free the array itself.  `clear()` destroys all of the remaining objects in the array, and sets the vector's `size` to 0, but it does not effect the vector's `capacity` (the allocated array).

Comment: Note `std::vector::shrink_to_fit` is a non-binding request.

Comment: That's what italicized *request* was supposed to indicate. Clarified.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Last question, is the memory slots associated to each element of a used to save pointers only?

Comment: @songyuanyao You are right. But I wonder what would happen before shrink_to_fit.

Comment: @Resorter: again, do you even understand what an array actually is?  If you don't, then you won't understand how a `vector` works internally.  If you have a `vector` of `T` elements, then you have a dynamically allocated `T[size]` array (ie `T *array = new T[size]`).  Each element is of size `sizeof(T)`, where `T` may or may not be a pointer. So, a `vector<double>` is basically like `double *array = new double[size]`, `vector<vector<double>>` is basically like `vector<double> *array = new vector<double>[size]`, etc. The actual details are a bit more complex, but that is a simple overview.